# This setting is enforced by your administrator

Tags: google-chrome

I'm using chromium web browser on Ubuntu 16.04. After signing in to chromium, there are some tools that I couldn't set for example: on startup, home page, show the bookmarks bar. The message is "this setting is enforced by your administrator. So, how can I set my own home page, on startup, and show the bookmarks bar.

I appreciate
Thank you

Comment: 1. Is this your personal PC, or does an organization own it? 2. Are you signed in to Chrome? If so, is it with a personal Gmail account, or an organization's account?

Comment: I'm a student and I'm using @southseattle.edu to sign in. It is my personal PC.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that those settings are being enforced by southseattle.edu due to you signing in with an account belonging to them. When you signed in with this account, you got a warning explaining this. Signing out of the account should return control to you.

Comment: Thank you very much. After signing out, i can change my homepage.